# Unity3D - How can I destroy one of two colliding objects with the same scripts and variables

Tags: windows

So my question is sort of simple I guess. I've got two objects that are exactly the same, same tags, name, etc.

Now I would like to make it so that when they collide with OnCollisionEnter, that a script chooses only ONE of them to destroy.

Is there any way I can accomplish this? I've thought of different things such as choosing a random number, timers.... sigh.

To clarify: I'm trying to detect collision on **two objects** with the **exact same variables** and simply choose **one** to act upon **ON COLLISION, not before**.

As a temporary solution, I'm checking the instance ID of the two colliding objects, and the one with the largest ID is chosen to act.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps destroy the one with the lower `rigidbody.velocity.magnitude`

It's very unlikely they would have identical speeds, however if they do maybe add a small random offset whenever you set a force.

Comment: Hmmmm. That's an idea. But what if they do? If you programmatically make each object move at a speed of 5?

Comment: I'm just using the object's instance ID for now and the one with the largest instance ID is destroyed.